# Ivy, Maven - Map transitive dependency

Tags: java, maven, ivy

Let's say we have bunch of artefacts, all of which have a child/transitive dependency on

```
artefact{group=zambia, id=zebra}
```

For reasons beyond my comprehension, some smart fella updated whatever used to be called artefact{group=zambia, id=zebra} to

```
artefact{group=africa, id=hello-zebra}
```

leaving a whole bunch of artefacts losing their child references to {zambia:zebra}

Let's also say that for reasons beyond my explanation, I am unable to get those parent artefacts pom or ivy.xml updated to instead having dependency on {africa:hello-zebra}.

**Question**:

Is there a way in my pom and/or ivy.xml to redirect any transitive dependencies on {zambia:zebra} to {africa:hello-zebra}?

Comment: Not clear to me how this is an ivy question. What repository is used to store the artifacts? Maven or Ivy? I suspect this is a problem with Maven parent/child POM relationships. Some more information would be helpful.

Comment: This is indeed both an Ivy and Maven question. I am simply using maven terminology to ask the question. I do need an answer on how to redirect from one Ivy artefact org:name to another artefact org:name. The repo service produces both maven and ivy artefacts.

Comment: Surely a fixed version of a module, has a dependency on another fixed version of module. It's not clear to me how a new revision changes a previous one....

Comment: Imagine a soft-link to a directory (either unix or win). Someone renamed the dir and now the softlink is orphaned. There are now hundreds of softlinks linked to the now renamed directory. I want a mapper to map all the softlinks to the newly named directory.

Comment: The whole point of a repository is to keep a unchanging copy of older releases. You cannot change these older versions and expect your build clients to fix the problem, that is missing the whole point.... Forgive me, I remain puzzled....

Comment: There are people smarter than I am, whose decisions I can't control, who decide to change artefact names without needing my consent, the structure of whose nexus server over which I have no say.

Comment: Well, that is a receipe for build instability and failure. For the same reason it's a bad idea to go back to previous source code revisions in SCM system (like Subversion) and change the contents... You're only valid approach is to go to the build clients (Maven and ivy) and revise the dependency listings to match the new names. Now... If your POM files in Nexus also need to be updated... Then you're really have few options apart from correcting all the dependencies there as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about Ivy but for Maven check this article out:

http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-relocation.html

It looks like uploading a *pom.xml* to your repository for your old artifact with a `relocation` element might do the trick:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>zambia</groupId>
  <artifactId>zebra</artifactId>
  <version>????</version>
  <distributionManagement>
    <relocation>
      <groupId>africa</groupId>
    </relocation>
  </distributionManagement>
</project>
```